# Python Rounding

Tags: python, rounding, precision

I'm working with latitude/longitudes that end in either `.25` or .`75`. I want to prompt a user for a lat/lon and have the program round it to a lat/lon ending in .25 or .75. I cannot round to .00 or .5, ONLY .25 or .75.

For examaple, if a user enters 43.04, I need Python to round that to 43.25.

I'm using Enthought Canopy Python distribution and am new to Python. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow James. If you google "rounding in python" I think that you will find your answer.

Comment: Try `0.5 * math.floor(2.0 * your_number) + 0.25`.

Comment: Can they end in `.0` or `0.5`?

Comment: What should something like `43.45` to round to? What about `43.5`?

Comment: You can multiply by 4, round to an integer and divide by 4. Not very elegant, but simple :

`round(43.15 * 4) / 4.`

returns `43.25`. You can also play with the modulo operator:

`43.15 - (43.15 % 0.25)`

but that will always round down.

Comment: Solution on my paste... I can't answer this question, don't know why http://pastebin.com/6BhChkBN

Comment: @xPino - You can't answer this question because answers are closed on duplicates. There are already answers on the linked question.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: It's not clear that it's a duplicate, though.  The OP seems to be asking about rounding to the nearest number that ends in .25 or .75, rather than just rounding to the nearest quarter.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yeah, but what about Adi answer??

Comment: If the OP indicates that he wants more than just quarter-intervals, I'll reopen it.

Comment: I understood the question has having customized intervals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work as a custom rounding function:

```
def customRound(num, d = [0.0, 0.25, 0.75, 1.0]): # you can change this list to any e.g. [0.0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 1.0]
     dec = num%1
     r = num - dec
     round_dec = min([(abs(i - dec),i) for i in d])[1]
     return r + round_dec
```

You can use it like this:

```
>>> customRound(9.34)
9.25
>>> customRound(9.4)
9.25
>>> customRound(9.98)
10.0
>>> customRound(9.8)
9.75
```